# Why zipping HDF5 file is still getting a good amount of compression even if all datasets are compressed inside the file?

Tags: compression, hdf5, h5py, pytables, hdf

I am using HDF5 file system in my desktop application. I have used GZIP level 5 compression with all the datasets inside the file.

But still **when I am zipping the HDF5 file using 7zip, the file size is getting even smaller by around half to one third**!!!

The process I am following is:

1. Generating the HDF5 file.
2. Importing data in the file.
3. Freeing up unaccounted space, if any, using h5repack utility.
4. Using 7zip I am zipping the file to .zip

How is it possible?

Where is the scope of more compression?

How to generate an even smaller HDF5 file? Any suggestions about the using property(H5P).

I thought that 7zip maybe ruthlessly compressing my file using GZIP level 9 but I tried using GZIP level 9 in my HDF5 file. New file size is still the half of the original.

Comment: Each chunk of data, is compressed on its own. So the first question is, what is your chunksize/shape? You do use shuffle right? (otherwise the compression ratio can be much worse)

Comment: Yes, I am using shuffle before zipping. I am storing 10k points per dataset and I am using the chunk size of 5k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying compression to only the dataset elements in the HDF5 file.  Other components of the HDF5 file (internal metadata and objects such as groups) aren't compressed.  So, when you compress the entire file, those other components compress, and the already compressed dataset elements could compress some more also.

Answer (score 3):

gzip has a maximum compression ratio of about 1000:1. If the data is more compressible than that, then you can compress it a second time to get more compression (the second time could be gzip again). You can do a simple experiment with a file consisting of only zeros:

```
% dd ibs=1 count=1000000 < /dev/zero > zeros
% wc -c zeros
1000000
% gzip < zeros | wc -c
1003
% gzip < zeros | gzip | wc -c
64
```

So what was the compression ratio of your first compression?

Comment: Mark, HDF5 uses compression in a very different way. For example, we zip 3 `.docx` files(file1.docx, file2.docx,file3.docx) and we get one zip(document.zip). So one zip container has 3 files. Now, when you have to use file2.docx, you will unzip documents.zip and then use file2.docx. Hence, this is a case of applying compression over multiple files.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You did not answer my question. What is the compression ratio of the HDF5 file?

Comment: Compression ratio varies inside the HDF5 file and depends upon chunking. In my case, different groups have different types of compound datasets. So I am using different chunk size in each dataset. Hence the compression ratio is varying from 2:1 to 47:1 within one HDF5 file using GZIP level 5.
This file size is 3.14 MB.

If I zip this 3.14 MB HDF5 file, zip file size is 1.27MB.

Comment: Then you do not have entries that saturate the ability of gzip to compress. The other answer that there are large portions of your file not compressed at all is likely the reason.